# How do I enable SSL for a local SignalR web server to allow flutter to connect to it?

Tags: flutter, signalr

Trying to use SignalR in main():

```dart
final connection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('https://localhost:44320/chat-hub',
      HttpConnectionOptions(
        logging: (level, message) => print(message),
      )).build();

  await connection.start();

  connection.on('ReceiveMessage', (message) {
    print(message.toString());
  });
```

This works, handshake successful, and I get a message from the server but then it decides to fatally crash with:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: The remote computer refused the network connection.


#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:94:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _MainPageState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:multipanel_chatwoot/presentation/pages/home_page.dart:22:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I googled it and it says change localhost to your ip, so I changed it to:
`...withUrl('https://192.168.1.39:44320/chat-hub'...`

But then I get the following when sending negotiation request:

```
flutter: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:393))
flutter: Failed to start the connection: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:393))
flutter: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error '{HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:393)).toString()}'.
```

So I try just change from https to http instead:
`flutter: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Connection closed before full header was received`

After a google search it suggests adding the following (of course only for local dev not production use):

```dart
// in main()
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}
```

but then I get:
`flutter: Failed to start the connection: Exception: Unexpected status code returned from negotiate '400'`

If I try adding `skipNegotiation: true` to the `HttpConnectionOptions` then I get `flutter: Failed to start the connection: Exception: Negotiation can only be skipped when using the WebSocket transport directly.`